# Hashnode API with GraphQL API resulting in error

Tags: vue.js, axios, graphql

I am trying to call the hasnode API to get blogs as the response, the body is in GraphQL. But I get this error in the Network Tab 'POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?'
`

```
let query = `
    {
      user(username: "singhmona") {
        publication {
          posts{
            slug
            title
            brief
            coverImage
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  let body = JSON.stringify({
            query
        });
   axios
      .post('https://api.hashnode.com/',
      body,
      {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response;
        console.log(response);}
        )
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using fetch. I've had a tough one with axios when using it in node and I was finally able to get the api to work with fetch. Here is a snippet of what worked for me.

```js
const getData = async() => {
const query = `
        {
        user(username: "misiochaabel") {
            publication {
                posts(page: 0) {
                    slug
                    title
                    brief
                    coverImage
                }
            }
            }
        }
    `;

        const response = await fetch('https://api.hashnode.com/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }
```